# What is the correct way to get the real file path from uri?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy

I created a file picker in my application. The first idea was, after the user pick a file, I concert to bae64 string and temporary I save it in the room database, while it won't be uploaded to the server. Unfortunatelly the room doesn't like files over 2 mb, so I get exception.

Se after that, I thought that, I store just the file path, and later I check the file if exists, and if it is, then I convert to base64 and upload the server.

It seems a good idea, but I can't open the file, because the file path doesn't exists. I checked File.exists but it always return false.

I use my application private storage because of android 11.

The path which is provided by uri.path gives this string: "/document/document:690"
But my file is locatid in Download folder(not inside my application folder). The uri is good, because I can open the file from my application.

The plan B is that, all the files which the user choose, I create a copy in my private directory, and with the file name and the extension, I can check it is exists

```
0. Camera and file picker

private fun openFilePicker() {
        try {
            myFileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            myFileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            myFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            myFileIntent.type = "*/*"
            startActivityForResult(myFileIntent, RequestCodes.DocumentUploadSelectFileRequestCode.code)
        }catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException){
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.not_found_application_label),false)
        }
    }

    private fun openCameraIntent() {
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

        try {
            val photoFile = documentManagerService.createFile(requireActivity(),Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,".jpg","IMG",true)
            imageFilePath = photoFile?.path

            photoFile?.let {
                val photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),requireContext().packageName,photoFile)
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoUri)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,RequestCodes.DocumentUploadTakePictureRequestCode.code)
            }
        }catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException){
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.not_found_application_label),false)
        }
    }

1. Activity Result
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            //Pick files
            RequestCodes.DocumentUploadSelectFileRequestCode.code -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    data?.let { it ->
                        if (it.clipData != null) {
                            for (i in 0 until it.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                                it.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri?.let { uri ->
                                    documentManagerService.getFileMetaData(uri,requireContext(),requireActivity())?.let {
                                        viewModel.addDocumentView(it)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            it.data?.let { uri ->
                                documentManagerService.getFileMetaData(uri,requireContext(),requireActivity())?.let {
                                    viewModel.addDocumentView(it)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Take a picture
            RequestCodes.DocumentUploadTakePictureRequestCode.code -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    imageFilePath?.let {
                        val file  = File(it)
                        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),requireContext().packageName,file)
                        documentManagerService.getFileMetaData(uri,requireContext(),requireActivity())?.let { documentView ->
                            viewModel.addDocumentView(documentView)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

2. Get file meta data

override fun getFileMetaData(uri: Uri,context: Context): DocumentView? {
        val documentView = DocumentView()
        val cursor: Cursor?
        documentView.uri = uri
        documentView.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

        if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            uri.path?.let {
                val file = File(it)
                documentView.name = file.name
                documentView.extension = file.extension
                return documentView
            }
        } else {
            val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    var size = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)

                    documentView.name =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
                }
                
                documentView.filePath = uri.toString()

                val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                documentView.extension = mimeType.getExtensionFromMimeType(
                    contentResolver.getType(
                        uri
                    )
                ) ?: "N/A"

                return documentView
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e)
            } finally {
                cursor?.close()
            }
        }

        return null
    }

3. Check the sync status, where is the file

      private fun openOrDownloadFile(documentView: DocumentView) {

        //The file is exists on server, have to download
        if (viewModel.customerComplaint.value?.syncStatus == 2) {
            viewModel.downloadDocument(documentView.id)

            //There is in somewhere in local storage
        } else {
            //val existingFile = documentManagerService.getFileIfExists(documentView.name,documentView.extension,requireActivity())

            //create Uri from saved uri string
            val u = Uri.parse(documentView.filePath)
            openFile(u, documentView.extension)
        }
    }

4. Get Intent based on uri

    override fun getFileIntent(extension: String,uri: Uri) : Intent {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

            if (extension == "jpeg" || extension == "jpg" || extension == "png")
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/$extension")
            else
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/$extension")

        return intent
    }


5. Open File

private fun openFile(uri: Uri, extension: String) {
        try {
            startActivity(documentManagerService.getFileIntent(extension, uri))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.can_not_open_the_file_label), false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `It seems a good idea,` No. Converting to base64 before uploading is never a good idea as it makes the amout of bytes to be transferred bigger.

Comment: `The path which is provided by uri.path gives this string: "/document/document:690"` That is a path for the provider. But not a file system path. So unusable for File class.

Comment: `. The uri is good, because I can open the file from my application.` Well then.. why are you messing around with a path? Use that uri!

Comment: I tried to save the uri, with uri.toString(), and in the other fragment, I use this uri string to create the Uri, But, for the first time when  I saved and opened, worked well, but when I close the app, the can not open the file. Maybe permission error? I will post the open file method

Comment: I updated the post, and you can see the full code

Comment: I'am sorry, this part left behind, updated

Comment: ok, now I understand, I added

Comment: Replace `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` by `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and take persistable uri permissions in onActivityResult. After that you can save data.getData().toString() and use next month.

Comment: Google for takePersistableUriPermission(currentUri, takeFlags);.

Comment: Thanks, I thought trought your suggestion, are you sure about it it will work? I found the error, and it will permission error. So from the beginning, I pick files, which were not created by my app, for example a downloaded pdf by chrome. I can pick, and reopen, but if i save the uri string, and close the app, an another fragment I get permission error in Android 11. My current solution is, I copy the file to my private download folder, and save this file uri. It works perfectly.